# I can't slove this problem. My npx create-react-app and npm start don't work

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app

when i try to create a react app by npx create-react-app my-app then throw me this error -

npm ERR! Cannot read properties of null (reading 'pickAlgorithm')

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Tech Point\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2021-12-28T05_28_34_105Z-debug-0.log

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting my-app5/ from C:\Users\Tech Point
Done.

Comment: Please specify your problem. Not able to understand what you have asked

Comment: Do you use nvm or do you install node manually?

Comment: Reinstall your `node` and `npm` using `nvm`. This link is useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70418210/node-installation-messed-up-on-macos/70418290#70418290

Comment: Here is something very similar asked before: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69567381/getting-cannot-read-property-pickalgorithm-of-null-error-in-react-native)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following -

- Delete node-modules.
- Delete the given file.
- Run `npm cache clear --force`

If the above steps don't work then try the following -

Upgrade the NPM version to v7.23.0 or the latest stable version and do `npm install`.

The upgrade step was taken from this [Solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69597076)

Comment: when i use npm cache clear --force this (npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.) is the result . What can I do now?

Comment: try using `npm cache clean --force`

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue recently. Which Node version are you currently using?

`npx create-react myapp` worked when I upgraded from Node 12.22.7 to Node 16.13.1 .

Simply switching to Node version 14.0.0 or higher and npm 5.6 or higher should do the trick.

For your [reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html)

Answer (score -2):

check your internet connection then try again "npm create-react-app" command this thing worked in my case.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).